# How to change owner of rust's excutable build?

Tags: linux, rust

I need to run a program written in rust that needs the `NET_CAP_ADMIN` capability, actually for development purposes I'm building the binary and running the output with `sudo` but is uncomfortable.

So, I think a better way is create a user like `program_user` with the corresponding permissions for `NET_CAP_ADMIN` and change the ownership of executable from `my_user` to `program_user`.

But, my question is, exist any way to change change the ownership of rust's build output without changing all project folder ownership, and at the same without changing manually at every building?

Comment: Build it while logged in as the user you want to own it? Unless you're building as root, you'd rarely have the permissions to change the ownership arbitrarily.

Comment: Exact! I don't want to use root every time so that everything goes well, now I'm testing it, I just need that cargo is also available for the new user, I'll solve it and I'll let you know how it went.